# how to pass 'this' reference in object fast initialization

Tags: c#, class, generics, initialization, this

For example:

```
List<Projects> projectList = new List<Projects>
{
    new Project
    { 
         id = 100500, 
         Subprojects = new List<Subproject>
         {
             new Subproject { Project = "**Need to pass pointer on the project**" },
         }
    }
}
```

How it possible to pass this pointer?

*It's a question just about syntax, I clearly understand that it possible to do that another way.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it in a single statement: the pointer (actually, the reference) that you would like to be assigned to `Project` is not allocated at the time you want to assign it. You need to use an intermediate variable - for example, like this:

```
Project p;
List<Projects> projectList = new List() {
    p = new Project() { 
        id = 100500
    ,   Subprojects = new List<Subproject>()
    }
};
p.Subprojects.Add(
    new Subproject { Project = p }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

How about just adding standard functions/constructors to each of the classes?

For example:

```
List<Project> cProjects = new List<Project> { new Project(100500) }; 

public class Project
{
    public Project(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
        Subprojects = new List<Subproject> { new Subproject(this) };
    }
    public int id;
    public List<Subproject> Subprojects;
}
public class Subproject
{
    public Subproject(Project project)
    {
        this.Project = project;
    }

    public Project Project;
}
```